# What happens on GetMessage failure?

Tags: c++, winapi

If GetMessage(...) fails, does the message not get removed from the message queue? I ask because when I have the following loop, I will eventually enter an infinite loop attempting to process the same message over and over:

```
while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, WM_SPEVENT, WM_SPUUIEVENT ))
{ 
      //Do something with my message. (Translate + dispatch perhaps, if I wanted)
}
```

Because I am not handling the case of GetMessage failure, will the loop get stuck on the same message over and over? Is this why the following is the correct way to implement a loop?:

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, WM_SPEVENT, WM_SPUUIEVENT )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something with my message
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `GetMessage` fails and returns `-1`, then typically your first code block would indeed result in an infinite loop. And so, if `-1` is a possible return value, that is why you see MSDN samples of the form of your second block of code.

However,

```
GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_SPEVENT, WM_SPUUIEVENT)
```

never fails and so never returns `-1`. The failure modes for `GetMessage` are where `&msg` refers to invalid memory, or where the second parameter, the window handle, is invalid. Neither failure mode can occur here, assuming of course that `msg` is properly defined. Typically it's a local variable, and so `&msg` is always fine.

Raymond Chen covered this here: [When will GetMessage return -1?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. The bit from Raymond Chen is a great resource as well -- thank you!